# Repeat CSS Style Every Nth Element

Tags: css, atom-editor

I am formatting the color of my Atom indent guide lines.

The Atom stylings are in CSS but I can't figure out **how to repeat the pattern.**

This is what is looks like at moment:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
.editor {

  .indent-guide {

      // first level
      color: rgb(255, 140, 0);

      // second level
      &:nth-child(2) {
          color: rgb(138,43,226);
      }

      // third level
      &:nth-child(3) {
          color: rgb(46,139,87);
      }

  }

}
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***repetition*** is missing: you are targeting 2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> child only, as exception to the first rule which is applied to all `.indent-guide` elements.

Use instead  `3n + 1` and `3n + 2`

```
.editor {

  .indent-guide {

      // first level
      color: rgb(255, 140, 0);

      // second level
      &:nth-child(3n + 1) {
          color: rgb(138,43,226);
      }

      // third level
      &:nth-child(3n + 2) {
          color: rgb(46,139,87);
      }

  }

}
```